# How to Display a user's name in Account with Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, firebase-authentication

I'm still somewhat new to firebase and react native. When a user successfully signs in I want to retrieve and display a user's first name from firebase.

Instead of hard coding the temp name 'Hussnain_sarwar' inside my Account.js file, I want to display a user's first name. I don't know the proper syntax to do this and I'm not sure if this requires Redux but if it does I definitely require help haha.

If I can see how this is done I can figure out how to to fetch and display other user information like address, inventory, and etc.

**SignIn.js**

```
firebase
      .auth()
      .signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log('User is signed in');
        if(result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser){


        firebase
        .database()
        .ref(`/users/${result.user.uid}`)
        .set({
          gmail: result.user.email,
          profile_picture: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.picture,
          locale: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.locale, //what location you're in
          first_name: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.given_name,
          last_name: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.family_name,
          created_at: Date.now()
        })
        .then(function(snapshot) {

        });
      } else {
        firebase
        .database()
        .ref(`/users/${result.user.uid}`)
        .update({
          last_logged_in: Date.now()
        });
      }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle Errors here.
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        const email = error.email;
        // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
        const credential = error.credential;
        // ...
      });
    } else {
      console.log('User already signed-in Firebase.');
      }
    },
  );
};
```

**Account.js**

```
render() {
    const {
      navigation: { navigate }
    } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={[commonStyles.flex1, { backgroundColor: '#000000' }]}>
      <Header>
          <Text
            style={[
              styles.TextColor,
              commonStyles.font18,
              commonStyles.textBold
            ]}
          >
            My Account
          </Text>
        </Header>
        <View style={[commonStyles.alignSelfcenter, commonStyles.mt20]} />
        <View style={[commonStyles.alignSelfcenter, commonStyles.mt20]}>
          <Text
            style={[
              commonStyles.textWhite,
              commonStyles.font16,
              commonStyles.textBold
            ]}
          >
            Hussnain_sarwar
          </Text>
        </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either pass data of user from one screen to other, In your case it's from **signin screen** to **accounts screen** or use Redux to store user data and access it through props.

Send Route Params:

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteName', { /* params go here e.g. user: { name: "test" } */ })
```

Access Route Params:

```
this.props.navigation.getParam(paramName, defaultValue)
```

Check this [React Navigation Route Params](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html)

Comment: so when the user successfully signs in I would do
inside my Account screen I would this.props.navigation.getParam(first_name, result.additionalUserInfo.profile.given_name)

??

Comment: Yes. When you sign in, in success callback move to account screen with route Params that you needed on accounts screen. Then access it on accounts screen by using getParams method of react navigation or you can access it through props. It's available in this.props.navigation.state.params here.